# Getting Android CallLogs Date Issue

Tags: android, date, time, calllog

I am trying to list incoming calls with names and dates/times;

```
        String[] _Projection = new String[]{CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                CallLog.Calls.DATE};
        String[] _ARGS = {String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE)};
        Cursor _cursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, _Projection, CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=?", _ARGS, null);
        int _num = _cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int _tip = _cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int _name = _cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        int _date = _cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
```

When I add these two lines the application stops;

```
        String strDate = _cursor.getString(_date);
        long lng = Long.parseLong(strDate);
```

Or with this line;

```
        long __lngDate = _cursor.getLong(_date);
```

Without these lines , application works without dates/times... What am i doing wrong?

NOTE: There is also permission with READ_CALL_LOG

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle args) {
    Log.d("CallLogs", "onCreateLoader() >> loaderID : " + loaderID);

    switch (loaderID) {
        case URL_LOADER:

            String mSelectionClause = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE+ " >= ?";
                String[]mSelectionArgs = {createDate()};
            // Returns a new CursorLoader
            return new CursorLoader(
                    mContext,   // Parent activity context
                    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,        // Table to query
                    null,     // Projection to return
                    mSelectionClause,            // No selection clause
                    mSelectionArgs,            // No selection arguments
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE + " desc"             // Default sort order
            );
        default:
            return null;
    }

}


 public  String createDate()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    return String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
```